# Question: how to implement A=a/1, B = b/3, C=A+B that results in C = a/1 + b/3?

Tags: prolog

I am very new to Prolog, and would appreciate any help.
I want to implement the following in Prolog:
combine (A,B,C)
  D = A/1,
  E = B/3,
  and C = A + B , in which given expression of A,B, C will return as A/1 + E/3, rather than calculating its value.
Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please go through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are very new to Prolog, then the best place to start is to go through some basic Prolog tutorials or a good Prolog text book. Once you become familiar with how Prolog works, you can attempt your problem and then ask a more specific question.

Comment: By the way, with just a little effort, run Prolog and, at the prompt, type the following: `A = a/1, B = b/3, C = A+B.` What result do you get?